# Scala-Spark(version1.5.2) Dataframes split error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an input file `foo.txt` with the following content:

```
c1|c2|c3|c4|c5|c6|c7|c8|
00| |1.0|1.0|9|27.0|0||
01|2|3.0|4.0|1|10.0|1|1|
```

I want to transform it to a `Dataframe` to perform some `Sql` queries:

```
var text = sc.textFile("foo.txt")
var header = text.first()
var rdd = text.filter(row => row != header)
case class Data(c1: String, c2: String, c3: String, c4: String, c5: String, c6: String, c7: String, c8: String)
```

Until this point everything is ok, the problem comes in the next sentence:

```
var df = rdd.map(_.split("\\|")).map(p => Data(p(0), p(1), p(2), p(3), p(4), p(5), p(6), p(7))).toDF()
```

If I try to print `df` with `df.show`, I get an error message:

```
scala> df.show()
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
```

I know that the error might be due to the split sentence. I also tried to split `foo.txt` using the following syntax:

```
var df = rdd.map(_.split("""|""")).map(p => Data(p(0), p(1), p(2), p(3), p(4), p(5), p(6), p(7))).toDF()
```

And then I get something like this:

```
scala> df.show()
+------+---------+----------+-----------+-----+-----------+----------------+----------------+
|  c1  |     c2  |    c3    |     c4    |  c5 |     c6    |        c7      |       c8       |
+------+---------+----------+-----------+-----+-----------+----------------+----------------+
|     0|        0|         ||           |    ||          1|               .|               0|
|     0|        1|         ||          2|    ||          3|               .|               0|
+------+---------+----------+-----------+-----+-----------+----------------+----------------+
```

Therefore, my question is how can I correctly pass this file to a Dataframe.

EDIT: The error is in the first row due to `||` field without an intermediate space. This type of field definition depending on the examples works fine or crashes.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, on Spark 2.0 it works fine. (no ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on df.show())

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to comment that it is on Spark 1.5.2. I'll edit the question

Comment: Can't you rename the file into `.csv` and directly read it into a `df ` ?

Comment: @user1920212 No, still no luck. It just works on 1.5.2, too. My guess is that you have some weird line ending in your file, so it does not split the rows properly.

Comment: @jamborta I just modified the input file with some parameters I have just tried and it does not work, in case you wish to retry it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because one of your lines is shorter than the others:

```
scala> var df = rdd.map(_.split("\\|")).map(_.length).collect()
df: Array[Int] = Array(7, 8)
```

You can fill in the rows manually (but you need to handle each case manually):

```
val df = rdd.map(_.split("\\|")).map{row =>
  row match {
    case Array(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) => Data(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)
    case Array(a,b,c,d,e,f,g) => Data(a,b,c,d,e,f,g," ")
  }
}

scala> df.show()
+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3| c4| c5|  c6| c7| c8|
+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+
| 00|   |1.0|1.0|  9|27.0|  0|   |
| 01|  2|3.0|4.0|  1|10.0|  1|  1|
+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+
```

EDIT:

A more generic solution would be something like this:

```
val df = rdd.map(_.split("\\|", -1)).map(_.slice(0,8)).map(p => Data(p(0), p(1), p(2), p(3), p(4), p(5), p(6), p(7))).toDF()
```

If you assume that you always have the right number of delimiters, it is safe to use this syntax an truncate the last value.

Comment: The second fragment is what I was looking for, but I am missing something. In this example, the null field is in the last field, but imagine that it could be at any of the 8 columns. How would you generalize your code in order to work correctly given this suposition?

Comment: Why are you including `.map(_.slice(0,8))`?

Comment: Just to show that it's longer. It's not necessary if you just want to feed it into the case class.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to use databrick's csv parser.

Link : https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

To load your example :

I loaded a sample file similar to yours:

```
c1|c2|c3|c4|c5|c6|c7|c8|
00| |1.0|1.0|9|27.0|0||
01|2|3.0|4.0|1|10.0|1|1|
```

To create the dataframe use the below code:

```
  val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true") // Use first line of all files as header
    .option("inferSchema", "true") // Automatically infer data types
    .option("delimiter", "|") // default is ","
    .load("foo.txt")
    .show
```

I got the below output

```
+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+----+---+
| c1| c2| c3| c4| c5|  c6| c7|  c8|   |
+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+----+---+
|  0|   |1.0|1.0|  9|27.0|  0|null|   |
|  1|  2|3.0|4.0|  1|10.0|  1|   1|   |
+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+----+---+
```

This way you do not have to bother about parsing the file yourself. You get a dataframe directly